# What happens if i make a sintax error inside the my.cnf file in mysql?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I would like to know what happens if one or more options inside my.cnf file hahe a sintax error inside or a specific value that does not fit with the environment settings.
Will Mysql ignore or overwrite only that single option/variable or will the entire my.cnf file be corrupted?

Comment: It will stop your mysql server.

Comment: It won't stop until you restart your MySQL.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh my.cnf is set up before starting the myslq client so what do you mean by "it will stop your mysql server"?

Comment: It means that if any syntax error in `my.conf` and if you restart server then it will stop.

Comment: i am not talking about restarting, i am talking about setting up the cnf file and starting the mysql client for the 1 st time

Comment: It will the entire my.cnf file be corrupted.

Comment: mysql won't start. Thats it.